# Running Multiple Tor Instances in Windows from C# Application

Tags: c#, tor

I'm trying to start multiple Tor instances via a C# .NET application.  The first instance starts up great, but the rest exit immediately.

I am using a different Data Directory for each instance, and have in fact made a copy of the entire Tor directory for each instance.

Here is the code:

```
        pProcess = new Process();

        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ExePath);
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(ExePath);
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "DataDirectory \"" + Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory + "\\data\"";

        Process.Start();
```

I have tried with the "RunAsDaemon 1" and "--service" arguments and they made no difference.

I can see that the unique data directories are being used, as tor creates the state/lock/etc files in them.  What else am I missing?

Perhaps I should also note, I AM able to start one instance with my code, and one instance by manually opening "Start Tor Browser.exe"

Thanks

Comment: Have you configured each of them to listen on different ports (both proxy and control)?

Comment: Yes sorry, should have mentioned that.  The Listen and Control ports are both set in the respective torrc files.

Comment: if you "wait" for the process to exit and print out the exit code, is it different to zero, and if so, maybe the tor documentation provides info what this exit code means (if != 0)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  However, it seems it's just returning -1.